# Jordan's lemma with $\exp(iaz) = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Looking at the [Wikipedia page on Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma), the lemma applies for functions of the form $e^{iaz}g(z)$ where $a>0$.

The page says "for the case $a=0$, see the estimation lemma" but I do not see how the estimation lemma can be applied to this case?

Ultimately I want to show that $\int_C\frac{1}{z^2 +1}dz$ tends to 0 as the radius of $C$ (which is the semicircle on the upper half plane) tends to infinity. To be clear I am integrating along the semicircle $C$.

Comment: It os not clear what you want to show. I may help if you focus your question further.

Comment: @OliverDiaz thank you. I've added a few more details.

Comment: The standard way to do this with the estimation lemma is to get an upper bound for the integral in terms of the radius of your semicircle (let's say $R$) and then show that the limit as $R$ goes to $\infty$ is $0,$ which shows that the integral must also go to $0,$ by the same logic that makes the squeeze theorem work.

Comment: @StephenDonovan thank you but can it be done with Jordan's lemma?

Comment: The factor $\pi/a$ in Jordan's lemma is precisely why Jordan's lemma does not apply when $a = 0$ -- it fails to bound.

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate direct estimate. The semicircle $C_r$ can be parametrized as $t\mapsto re^{it}$ where $t\in [0,\pi]$. Also, we suppose $r>1$ so that the semicircle avoids the pole at $z=i$. Now,
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{C_r}\frac{dz}{z^2+1}\right|&=\left|\int_0^{\pi}\frac{rie^{it}\,dt}{(re^{it})^2+1}\right|\\
&\leq \int_0^{\pi}\left|\frac{rie^{it}}{(re^{it})^2+1}\right|\,dt\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{r}{\left|(re^{it})^2+1\right|}\,dt\\
&\leq \int_0^{\pi}\frac{r}{|(re^{it})^2|-1}\,dt\tag{*}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{r}{r^2-1}\,dt\\
&=\frac{\pi r}{r^2-1},
\end{align}
where we used the reverse triangle inequality in $(*)$. From this final inequality, it is clear that it approaches $0$ as $r\to \infty$.

Note that with some practice, you can immediately tell right from the integral $\int_{C_r}\frac{dz}{z^2+1}$ that because the length of $C_r$ is $\pi r$, while the $z^2$ in the denominator becomes an $r^2$ (the $+1$ in the denominator clearly doesn't matter if $r$ is very large), so the whole thing grows like $\frac{1}{r}$. The above calculation just makes this more explict.

---

Side comment: I would highly recommend you practice applying these sorts of estimates in your calculations repeatedly until it becomes second nature, rather than invoking various lemmas, because sometimes you may encounter a function for which a lemma/theorem may not apply directly because one or two of the assumptions are not satisfied. On the other hand, the proof idea of these lemmas/theorems can usually be easily adapted to a more general case (or sometimes, the proofs themselves contain stronger results than is actually stated in the theorem).